# frame_id for Turtlebot

Tags: ros, turtlebot, frame-id

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there anywhere that I can get a list of frame_ids (coordinate frames) for Turtlebot?
base_link
odom
kinect
?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70378/frame_id-for-turtlebot/) by [Solmaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2778/solmaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Checkout rqt_tf_tree

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rqt_tf_tree

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2013-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0